# How to call a macro name with _ from ExcelLink?

Tags: excel, excellink

I am running the latest version of `` ExcelLink` ``  and I am able to call macros with the name like `optimize` using:

```
ExcelRun["optimize"]
```

But I call a macro with name `b_optimize_model` using the same syntax:

```
ExcelRun["b_optimize_model"]
```

I get the error:

> ExcelRun::macro: b_optimize_model is not a valid macro name.

How do I call such a macro?

Comment: I have zero experience with ExcelLink, but as I recall, J/Link substitues `_` with `$`. Try that maybe?

Comment: .NET/Link maps to `U`, so you can try that as well https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromTheWolframLanguage.html

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope, not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: No, I never used ExcelLink, sorry.

Comment: I have no experience with it but can you run another macro without the `_` symbol in it? Try ```\``` before the ```_``` if you haven't already.

Comment: @Syed Tried that as well. Still not working.

Comment: On page 23 of the ExcelLink manual: `... and name the macro whatever you like. Spaces in the macro name are permitted.` I am afraid i have not tried it myself.